# mathastext font shapes rendered in wrong encoding

Tags: math-mode, greek, shapes, alphabet, mathastext

I am trying to use the `mathastext` package to replace alphabet letters in math with the default fonts in the document, and `gfsdidot` (`udidot`) for greek. I can either get everything relevant except greek working, or get greek working but break latin.

I use pdfLaTeX, and I think I have enough math alphabets, so that shouldn't be the issue. I also know that GFS Didot comes in all desired weights and shapes. How does an alphabet in `mathastext` know that it is only meant for greek and why does it not contain `\mathrm`? What is its relation to `\mathnormal` (which currently is equally broken)?

`\Mathrm` may seem like a syntax error but it is defined internally in `mathastext.sty`, though I am not sure how (or if) to properly use it.

If it's any help to convey what I am looking to do: something akin to what [`unicode-range`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40font-face/unicode-range) does in CSS, to use one font for one range of characters, and another font for another range. For pdfLaTeX this seems to get harder because fonts are not in unicode, but it should indeed be possible, because `mathastext` does so properly for the default math alphabet. How?

[image: PDF output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[LGRgreek,italic]{mathastext}

\DeclareSymbolFont{mycustom}{LGR}{udidot}{normal}{n}
\SetSymbolFont    {mycustom}{normal}{LGR}{udidot}{\rmdefault}{n}%
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\Mathrm}{mycustom}%%% disable this to break greek but fix latin

\MTgreekfont{udidot}
\MTitgreek
\MTitGreek
\Mathastext

\newcommand*{\GRALPH}{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon
\zeta \eta \theta \iota \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi o \pi
\rho \sigma \tau \upsilon \phi \chi \psi \omega \varsigma}

\newcommand*{\gralph}{A B \Gamma \Delta E Z H \Theta I K
\Lambda M N \Xi O \Pi P \Sigma T \Upsilon \Phi X \Psi \Omega}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\( \GRALPH - \mathrm{\GRALPH} \)\\
\( \gralph - \mathrm{\gralph} \)\\
so far it looks good, but now also latin turns up as greek:\\
\( abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz - \mathrm{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \)

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you would like `\mathrm` to turn the Greek letters upright. The `\Mathrm` is a math alphabet defined by mathastext designed to use the text font (which is already used for the letters in math) in the default shape, which a priori is upright. (so this makes sense if the package received `italic` option). Then `\mathrm` is simply re-defined to be the macro with meaning `\Mathrm` (so option `defaultmathalphabets` is implemented by just not doing that definition).

In LaTeX NFSS, `\mathrm` means to use the text font in math. It doesn't mean to turn things upright. In particular it makes no sense, a priori, to expect it to turn Greek letters from italic to upright shape.

But you can define a math alphabet command `\upgreek` which will use a given font in LGR encoding having upright Greek letters. Indeed, mathastext makes sure the Greek letters obey math alphabet commands.

So, possibly, this achieves what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[LGRgreek,italic]{mathastext}
\MTitgreek
\MTgreekfont{udidot}
\Mathastext

\DeclareSymbolFont{mycustom}{LGR}{udidot}{m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\upgreek}{mycustom}

\newcommand*{\GRALPH}{\alpha \beta \gamma \delta \epsilon
\zeta \eta \theta \iota \kappa \lambda \mu \nu \xi o \pi
\rho \sigma \tau \upsilon \phi \chi \psi \omega \varsigma}

\newcommand*{\gralph}{A B \Gamma \Delta E Z H \Theta I K
\Lambda M N \Xi O \Pi P \Sigma T \Upsilon \Phi X \Psi \Omega}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\( \GRALPH - \upgreek{\GRALPH} \)\\
\( \gralph - \upgreek{\gralph} \)\\
so far it looks good.\\
\( abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz - \mathrm{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz} \)

\meaning\mathrm
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately `\mathrm{\upgreek{\alpha\beta ab}}` will not work, because the `\upgreek` will override the exterior `\mathrm`. LaTeX math alphabets just don't nest.

If you need a macro `\uprightlatinandgreek` then it might be possible, but if you don't I can rest a bit `;-)`.

[image]

Comment: background: `mathastext` does not modify that in math mode textfont family "0" still refers to ComputerModern, as set-up by LaTeX. So it needs a custom `\Mathrm` to switch to the document text font, in contrast to Computer Modern (or whatever replaced it if some math font package was loaded). By default, it does `\renewcommand\mathrm{\Mathrm}`. But in "subdued" mode, the normal and bold math versions will recover the original meaning of `\mathrm`.

Comment: You're right; I would like `\mathrm` to act similarly as `\textrm`, even though stacking doesn't work. (for that we have `\boldsymbol`) Could `mathastext` maybe be made to play nice with `isomath`? Or could the OT1(?) `\mathrm` family be extended with with the LGR characters?

Comment: Traditional TeX works with font files having 256 slots. The math alphabets simply select a font. The command `\alpha` in math mode is declared to use a given slot in a given (math) font. `mathastext`, with option `LGRgreek` makes it slot number 97. It also tells TeX that `\alpha` is of "variable family type". So inside say `\mathrm`, `\alpha` will give the character at slot 97 in what ever font `\mathrm` command has been configured to use. In the case of `mathastext`, `\mathrm` gives `\Mathrm`, and `\Mathrm` is configured to use the text-font. Thus in 99% of cases slot 97 will give letter "a".

Comment: This all means that "extending `\mathrm` with LGR characters" can not work with the LaTeX native mechanisms. However we can naturally define `\alphaup` etc... symbols, and let our macro `\uprightletters` do both of `\mathrm` and `\let\alpha\alphaup` etc... where `\alphaup` will have been defined as a symbol _not reacting to math alphabets_. This is possible approach. Is it really worthwile, in comparison to simply use directly `\alphaup` in mark-up? or for that matters `\upgreek{\alpha}` as in my answer? It is not clear to me what you mean by "play nice with isomath". Perhaps precisely this?

Comment: So I take it then that the default math alphabet works differently? Because with `mathastext` it's clear that both latin and greek from separate fonts can be used with the same markup. Or do the `\alpha` `\beta` etc. commands automatically change math alphabet, even though seemingly using the default?

Comment: (Why delete? Someone might have the same question.)

Comment: Considering what you said about `\mathrm` using the text font, I think the cleanest workaround would be to use `\text` with the [tag:alphabeta] package, still allowing name commands for greek letters, e.g.: `\text{\gamma}`.

Comment: @svenpar about deleting I was referring to my comment not to my answer ;-)

Comment: The background is that LaTeX uses _different font_ for Latin, Greek, etc.. to "using the text font" is not clear. By default, `mathastext` does not interfere with Greek, so indeed if some other package provides a solution to your issue, that could be best way.